# How to select first paragraph in html render react native

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-render-html, the renderers transfer p into text component, but it gives all paragraphs in html body with number of lines equal to 2, what I want is selecting only the first paragraph.

```
 <View style={{width:Dimensions.get('window').width-30}}>
  <HTML html={htmlContent}
  renderers={{
  p :(_, children) => <Text  numberOfLines={2}  >{children}</Text>
}}
   tagsStyles={{
       p:{
         marginBottom:20,
  fontSize:16
  }
 }}
   />
</View>
```

Here is the output if I put number of lines equal to 2, I have 5 paragraphs
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ6HK.png).

[Here is the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BKbL.png)

I try to use alterChildren with splice like the docs, but it never works and i never know where exactly i need to put it.

```
// ... your props
alterChildren: (node) => {
    const { children, name } = node;
    if (name === 'ol' && children && children.length) {
        // Keep only the first two elements of the list
        return children.splice(0, 1);
    }
    // Don't return anything (eg a falsy value) for anything else than the <ol> tag so nothing is altered
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "selecting only the first paragraph"? The `numberOfLines` does not refer to the number of paragraphs, it just defines that the text display can span multiple lines. Can you post the input and expected output for your use case?

Comment: I add the output to the post, if you can check(every p is ended by ...), i want the first p(first two lines) i tried  to put first child next to p but it never works.

Comment: you notice that they are not equal in length also.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not quite clear as to what you need as the output. Can you add the expected output to the question as well?

Comment: I added it to the question.